# Sharepoint 2007 Webpart variables problem on reload

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I'm having trouble with the webparts variables... I came from standard ASP language, so, to me, store variables in session and other parts is the common way to do everything =)

Now i had to create a webpart, the wp has to write a graph from parameter and i cannot understand HOW variables works: i cannot understand WHEN saved and WHEN erased and other thing like this!

Let me explain: i have a web part with the configuration toolbar on the right in which i put the values.. Everytime a button is pressed or a value in the dropdown list changes, it raises an event which causes the "CreateChild" function..

Many times the data is "stored", other time they are not!

That's the way i used to store value (in the ApplyChanges override function):

```
WPChartGenerator wpParent = (WPChartGenerator)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
wpParent.WebUrl = txtWebUrl.Text.Trim();
```

And in the CreateChild event i get the value like:

```
WPChartGenerator wpParent = (WPChartGenerator)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
this.ddlWeb = new DropDownList();
this.ddlWeb.ID = "ddlweb" + wpParent.ID;
ddlWeb.SelectedValue = wpParent.WebService;
```

Now.. Sometimes this works, for example, when i push a button I invoke in the code of the button and then the code to store every value.. In some case (like buttons) this works, in other (like dropdown list index changed event) this fails and i found every object in the wpParent equal to it's initial value.

Another thing i noticed, is that in certain cases when an event is triggered, the first thing to be executed (even first than the event's associated code) il CreateChild (even first than OnLoad!!!)

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing in the wrong way? Do anybody has a good tutoria for this matter?

Thanks & sorry 4 my School level English =)

Forget to say that every variable has been implemented as a Property, like that:

```
[WebBrowsable(false)]
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)]
public string WebUrl
{
    get
    {
        return this.webUrl;
    }
    set
    {
        this.webUrl = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see all the code there so I don't really know what you're doing wrong (i.e. do you actually have an ApplyChanges method) but from the way you've worded your question it sounds like you really need to start at the beginning, follow one of these walkthrough tutorials and make sure you understand the basics and then start adding in the code for your project.

[MSDN - Creating Web Parts for SharePoint (VS2010)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231579.aspx)

[MSDN - Walkthrough: Creating a Basic SharePoint Web Part (WSS 3.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452873%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

[Developing SharePoint 2007 Web Parts](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Developing-SharePoint-2007-Web-Parts.id-306330.html)

Comment: I don't mean to offend with the answer, but skipping the first steps you need to take in understanding how this all ties together will lead to trouble later.

Comment: I read many and many tutorials... I posted just 1% of the code i've written.. My problem is to understand HOW the properties were managed: when i push a button the variables may be kept, but when a dropdown list is scrolled and the event is generated every data is lost and reset!
What i really like to know if there is any element in which store my variable because with the method i've exposed it doesn't work as expected

Comment: State is normally kept by asp.net web controls in VIEWSTATE between page loads and then persisted by your code to the web part properties in ApplyChanges. Unless you do something very weird you don't have to worry about viewstate - it just works automatically. As for your comments about "CreateChild (even first than OnLoad!!!)" thats how its supposed to work. You can't issue a load event on a control before its been created. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Ok, so the right way to persiste some data is this?
Create some properties
Create an ApplyChanges which overrides and stores the data with the ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart object
In CreateChild load manually the data
Is this correct?
Sorry but i've a strange situation in which, to keep a password field filled, i must call some "CreateChild" manually and i think in that calls is the problem!
Thank you very much!

Comment: OK, now i understando what i've missed to say... In my app i've a bar to "fill" da data of the webpart which passes between many and many "CreateChild", this is because a user must insert credential and other things..

When the user push connect data are collected from a list inside a dropdown list which permits to select data to print in the graph (which is what user view of the entire project). In this kind of project i've many and many events which triggers the refresh and the state in some cases is saved in other it isn't!